# How to get Apples Human Interface Guidelines 2016 as epub or pdf file?

Tags: ios, documentation

How to get **iOS Human Interface Guidelines 2016** as epub or pdf file?

Comment: Keep in mind that Apple themselves do violate them. Typical example is Xcode UI.

Answer (score 1):

Download **iOS Human Interface Guidelines** book in iBooks.app then drag and drop the file out of the "shelve" into the Desktop (or any other folder). It'll appear as `.epub`.